# Is there a way to be calling a method constantly while the program is running in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ipad

I want to call a method infinitely while the program is running to check for the change of state of something. Is it possible to do this when programming for the iPhone?

Comment: Read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Comment: What you describe is called **polling** and you should try to avoid it if at all possible. If there is any other way to be notified of the change, such as a callback or other notification then use that instead. It would help a lot if we knew what the "something" was that you are trying to get the state of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible, just use a repeating `NSTimer`.

However I would advise against the continuous polling to get the state - better to setup a callback/delegate/notification pattern to notify any observers of a state change.

You could also use Key Value Observing (KVO) to get notified when a value is updated.

Lots of food for thought and terms to research.

Comment: In your app delegate.  But once again: try to look for another solution.

Comment: How is anything external to the app going to change the app state without polling though?  The only means really is a notification... but he may not have the infrastructure for that.

Comment: Not necessarily in the app delegate. In whatever object in your application is most relevant to the thing that is changing. But yes—any form of polling should be your *last* resort.